# how to run a loop for backward elimination for regression in R

Tags: r, function, loops, matrix, regression

I want to run a loop so that I can keep removing variables that has a P value more than SL = 5%.

I wanted to first define the first loop. I tried to create a matrix out of the summary of the regressor and then try to extract the 'row name. where the column name Pr(>|t|) has a value greater than 0.5. Then I want to use the row name to eliminate from the dataframe on which I am originally running the regression.

I can only extract the value and rowname, along with indice and don't know how do I use the row name to eliminate the column from the dataframe

```
\\data frame name is 'input'
\\set.seed(123)
\\split<- sample.split(input$Profit, SplitRatio = 0.8)
\\training_set<- subset(input, split == TRUE)
\\test_set<- subset(input, split == FALSE)

\\multiple_regressor<- lm(formula = Profit ~.,data = input)   
\\a<-summary(multiple_regressor)

\\which.max(a[["coefficients"]][2:6,"Pr(>|t|)"])
```

In the above line, I am getting the output as 'administration' (one of the x variables), and index - 2. I wanted to get only 'administration' and then eliminate the same from the df input and then re-run a loop.

when I use row.names with max (instead of which.max), then I am getting NULL.
Also, once I find it, how do I use it in the loop? Do I necessarily need to create a function?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. In your post there are many implicit and explicit questions. What did you try?

Comment: Try the `tidy` function in `broom` package to get the coefficient in more convenient from.

Comment: There are also a number of R packages that has functions for variable selection, `caret` and `MASS` for example.